# Using the cosine law: Given a $\triangle ABC$ with $AB=3$, $AC=8$, and median $AD=5$, find $BC$.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I'm trying to solve the following question but somehow got stuck with no clue how to continue:

> Given a $\triangle ABC$ with
> $$AB=3, AD=5, AC=8$$
> where $AD$ is the median of $BC$ (meaning $BD=DC$). Find $BC$.

I've used cosine law and reached that: $$ BD=\sqrt{34-30\cdot \cos y}$$
$$CD= \sqrt{89-80\cdot \cos a}$$
Not sure that I can assume that angle $a=y$ ($\angle DAB=\angle DAC$).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: [Applonius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27s_theorem#:~:text=In%20geometry%2C%20Apollonius's%20theorem%20is,median%20bisecting%20the%20third%20side%22.) kills it!

Comment: Haven`t learned about him , is there a way to solve it without that theorem ? only by using trigo?

Comment: @Tai Ouzan did you read the article completely? there *is* a proof by law of cosines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the cosine rule as follows instead
$$AB^2= AD^2+ BD^2 -2AD\cdot BD \cos \theta $$
$$AC^2= AD^2+ CD^2 - 2AD\cdot CD \cos (\pi-\theta )$$
Substitute $BD=CD=\frac12BC$ and eliminate the variable $\theta$ to obtain $BC$.

Answer (score 1):

By Applonius Theorem suggested by @AlbusDumbledore,
\begin{align}
AB^2 + AC^2 &= 2(AD^2+BD^2) \\
3^2 + 8^2 &= 2(5^2 + BD^2) \\
BD &= \frac12\sqrt{3^2 + 8^2 - 2\cdot 5^2} = \frac{\sqrt{23}}{2} \\
BC &=  2BD = \sqrt{23}
\end{align}

---

> Not sure that I can assume that angle $a=y$ ($\angle DAB=\angle DAC$).

No, $AD$ is median, not angle bisector.